# Not able to debug Outlook 2013 add-in project using outlook 2016

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I have created outlook 2013 add-in project using visual studio 2013.

I was able debug it on outlook 2013.

During upgrade of office products my outlook 2013 upgraded to outlook 2016.

Now I am not able to debug my project.

I tried giving path of new outlook in "Start external program" of Start action in Debug tab of project properties , then it gives error as

```
An add-in could not be found or could not be loaded

Could not load file or assembly 'OutlookPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
```

Can any one help me in how to debug outlook 2013 project in outlook 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any build errors or warnings? Did you have a chance to check out the list of references?

Try to replace the referenced Outlook 2013 interop assembly with the latest one which corresponds to Outlook 2016. That's how VSTO knows which Outlook version is to run. You need to choose Outlook 2016 on the COM references tab and the required interop file will be created for you.